# How to convert string into array of integers with determined width

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I need to convert string (for instance "1234567890") to array of integers but width of element is determined by user. So:

if user passed 1 it will be: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0

for 2 I will have an array: 12 34 56 78 90

3: 1 234 567 890

4: 12 3456 7890

etc.

What I tried:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string textNumber;
    int size;
    cin >> textNumber;
    cin >> size;

    int length = textNumber.length();
    int lenghtOfArray = length / size + (length % size ? 1 : 0);
    int myArray[lenghtOfArray] = {0};
    int move = lenghtOfArray- (size * lenghtOfArray - length);
    int copySize = size;
    int k = 0;

    for(int i=0; i < length;i++) {
        if(--copySize && !move){
            myArray[k] += (int)textNumber[i]-48;
        } else {
            myArray[k] += (int)textNumber[i]-48;
            ++k;
            copySize = size;
            if(move) --move;
            continue;
        }
        myArray[k] *= 10;
    }

    myArray[k] += (int)(textNumber[0]-48);

    for(int i=0; i < lenghtOfArray; i++) {
        cout << myArray[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

but It doesn't work for all cases ( I̶t̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶s̶ ̶o̶n̶l̶y̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶s̶i̶z̶e̶=̶2̶).

Comment: Define _doesn't work_.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It is easiest to provide help if we can reproduce the error you experience with the code you provide. If I copy/paste that code and try to compile it I will get a bunch of compiler errors that are not realted to your actual question.

Comment: i mean, why not just parse a series of substrings.  I dont really see that as a difficult resolution.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Some day soon the above comment will be used by parents to scare disobedient young programmers.

Comment: @user4581301 in fact it is already in use today :P

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ My problem is not in my code (of course there is also) but my problem is that I don't know how to do it, any algorithm. My is not working (and is not smart). I need a clue for how to implement this conversion.

Comment: @Fallenreaper how to do it in easiest way?

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz after you `substr` what you need, use `stoi`?

Comment: @Fallenreaper "stoi is not declared in this scope". I've added <string> and <sstream>

Comment: after googling, you should find a resolution to that.  I was not sure which version of c++ you were using.

Comment: Yes, I searched. There is some bug with MinGW. I am using c++11. I can use another function for "string to integer" conversion but is still not so easy. It is easy if I want do it from left to right (12345 -> 12 34 5) but not so easy to do it from right to left (12345 -> 1 23 45). I don't know how to split 12345 into "1" "23" "45" and "12" "345" etc. Conversion to int is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use `std::stoi` along with `substr` member function of `std::string` to break string into pieces and parse the results:

```
cin >> s;
cin >> size;
int len = s.length();
int count = (len+size-1) / size;
vector<int> res(count);
int pos = count-1;
while (s.length() > size) {
    res[pos--] = stoi(s.substr(s.length()-size));
    s = s.substr(0, s.length()-size);
}
if (s.length()) {
    res[0] = stoi(s);
}
```

Note that you need to use `std::vector<int>` instead of an array, because C++ standard does not allow variable-length arrays (g++ offers it as a popular extension).

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/tqYujM)

Comment: Yes it works! Please say me that it was not so easy and I don't need to think that I'm stupid. It is a part of bigger application and I get stuck only here.

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz It's not too easy, but I wouldn't call it too hard, either. Once you figure out how to chop the last `n` digits from a string, the rest of the program, sort of, "writes itself". Good luck with the bigger project!